Is it possible to set a jdk on an external mass storage?
At school I use my USB stick with VScode installed on it to use it on school PCs but every time I have this problem with the jdk.
Every time I run VScode on the PC it asks to install the jdk directly on the machine but to do this I need administrator permissions. Is there a way to set up the jdk directly on the USB and not on the machine? so as to bypass admin permissions?
I tried to install the jdk only locally so as not to use administration permissions but the setup is interrupted
